# Берутся ли в кавычки "челноки"?

Tags: пунктуация

В 90-е годы людей, которые ездили за границу за товаром, называли "челноками". А как пишется это слово: в кавычках или без?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от стиля речи. Словари [Ожегова](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/265294), [Кузнецова](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/kuznetsov/13486/%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA) и [Ефремовой](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/265566/%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA) дают помету прост. или разг. Следовательно, вне разговорного стиля речи, слово заключать в кавычки всё-таки желательно. При передаче же на письме разговорного стиля речи в интернет-сообщении,  литературном произведении, публицистическом произведении или в ином стиле речи смысла заключать слово "челнок" в кавычки уже нет.

Answer (score 4):

Это слово не нужно заключать в кавычки.

Answer (score 2):

А я думаю, что нужно писать в кавычках, потому что слово употреблено не в свойственном ему значении. Уважаемые сайты пишут с кавычками, а если без кавычек, то  "так называемые челноки".

Comment: Уважаемая Людмила! Спорить с Вами не буду, но, во-первых, следующие за так называемый слова не заключаются в кавычки (см. в пособии Е. Литневской) и, во-вторых, слово челноки, ссылаясь на Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук под ред. В. В. Лопатина, в кавычки не заключается. Может, другие словари и дают кавычки, но, если честно, я всецело доверяю словарям на ресурсе "Грамота.ру", и в своей работе ссылаюсь на них.

Comment: Во-первых, где Вы увидели у меня  кавычки после "так называемый"? я же написала: "Если без кавычек", а "так называемые челноки"- как цитата. Во-вторых, ссылочку на объяснение в словаре Лопатина не дадите? В словарной статье и не должно быть кавычек.Там и "летучая мышь" без кавычек, но если мы имеем в виду фонарь, то пишем в кавычках, чтобы указать на переносный смысл.И "козёл"(спортивный снаряд)без кавычек. А Вы как пишете - "прыгал через козла "или"прыгал через "козла"..."?

Comment: Правильно, словарь Лопатина правописание объясняет без кавычек, не ту ссылку нажала. Думаю, что это не такая уж большая погрешность с моей стороны. Но Вы же доверяете словарям на "Грамоте.ру", в частности Большому толковому словарю русского языка под  ред. С. А. Кузнецов? (Ссылки на словари рядом, поэтому и кликнула по ошибке). А там даже Ваш пример "прыгал через козла" и челноки пишутся без кавычек. Так кому же верить?